# Send updates about progress from Cloud Code to iOS device (Parse)

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

So I am using Parse Cloud Code to purchase a license for a user, and I would like to show the user the progress of the purchase. For this I would need a functionality similar to "response", however calling response exits the function. Is there an alternative to "response" function that would let let the code keep on executing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a Cloud Function is given 15 seconds to finish and then terminated, I don't think you would have much chance to show any progress anyway. If it is a multi-step process then you should probably use Promises in your client code with appropriate feedback there, e.g.:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('step1', {}).then(function (step1Result) {
    // show progress
    console.log('step 1 done');
    return Parse.Cloud.run('step2', { data: ... });
}).then(function (step2Result) {
    // show progress
    console.log('step 2 done');
    // add steps as needed
}, function (error) {
    // catch all errors here...
    console.log(error);
});
```